# How to know which word is selected in webpage using c#

Tags: c#

I am using C# **web application**

In my page I have to display long formated text (Bold/colored/etc)

in this text user can highlight any part of the text and then click a button, in the button they click I should read highlighted text.

I can build the text in html `<b> </b>`  or other tags for colours, etc.

but how to read the highlighted text and its location in the text?!

example

if user highlighted the 2nd word `today`

```
Hi 
How are you today? 
It is a beautiful day today. 
Would you like to go out?
```

and then clicked a button.

In this button I will get today

start position = 45

end position = 50

Comment: Is this for a web-, winforms or WPF project? What container/usercontrol is the text inside?

Comment: window.getSelection().toString() - did you tried this way with javascript(if is web what we are talking)?

Comment: yes, I am asking about web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mark` tag:

```
<mark>highlight</mark>
```

Comment: My question is about how to read the highlighted text, and its location in the text

Answer (score 2):

If JavaScript approach is ok for you, then it could be done like this:

```js
function getSelectionHtml() {
        
        var myContainer = document.getElementById("myDiv");
        var myContainerText = myContainer.innerText;

        var html = "";
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var container = document.createElement("div");
                for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                    container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
                }
                html = container.innerHTML;
            }
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
                html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
            }
        }
         var selectionLength = html.length;

         var selectionStartIndex = myContainerText.indexOf(html);
         var selectionEndIndex = selectionStartIndex + selectionLength;

         console.log("Selected text: " + html);
         console.log("Selected text from " + selectionStartIndex + " to " + selectionEndIndex + " of " + myContainerText.length);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDiv">Hello, here is a normal text and <b>some bold one</b> lorem ipsum </div>
    <input type="button" id="trigger" onclick="getSelectionHtml()" value="Check" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But the text you are using does not support formating. I want text to be colored and bolded :(

Comment: @asmgx, I've changed the code and it should support formatting. But one thing which for sure we should fix it's the case when you select the word and we have more than one occurrence inside.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short - tag `<mark>` shall suit your needs

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_mark.asp

Comment: this is not my question. My question is about how to read the highlighted text, and its location in the text

Comment: @asmgx Ah, I see. Well, in that case you need to receive it via Window.getSelection().toString() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection